# Mat Table does not work with Mat Sort and Service Api

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I need your help to order by column, the examples I have found work with mock data but not with services

**table.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatSortable } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name'];
  dataSource= new MatTableDataSource();
  data: any;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort!: MatSort;
  constructor(private service: DataService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getList(); 
  }

  getList() {
    this.service.getData()
    .subscribe((res:any)=> {
      this.dataSource.data = res;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      console.log('so',this.sort)
    })
    
  }

}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="position"> No. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.userId}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
  
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
```

data.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  }
}
```

on this example works fine but the version its 6  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-sort-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html but in my code doesnt

my example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g1qbd9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) but the version its 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Sort Header (Using sort with the mat-table section)](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#using-sort-with-the-mat-table),

> When used on a mat-table header, it is not required to set a mat-sort-header id on because by default it will use the id of the column.

The column sorting is based on the column id which is `matColumnDef`.

Make sure that the column id must be matched with the data property in order to make the sorting works.

> table.component.ts

```js
displayedColumns = ['title', 'userId'];
```

> table.component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
    No.
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.title }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
    Name
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.userId }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f2ktv9?file=src/app/table/table.component.html)

Comment: Yesterday I just found that answer, anyway thanks